# should i do commit after every execute or after loop

Tags: python, oracle

I have 2000 inserts in a loop
I do execute sql

My question is: should i do commit after every execute or after loop in order to minimise my affect on locking table and don't care about buffer?

the problem: my script sending to much queries and they stand in wait

I don't ask about limits of sql for x rows in commit and not about rollback in code. My question is about queue that standing half day in oracle server inactive and some waiting and prevent to new one proccess to run.

Comment: Could you share some additional context about your implementation, especially how you're connecting to the database? Are you using an ORM?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use a loop to do the insert? Most often it can be rewritten to a single insert statement. Please edit your question to include sample code that demonstrates what you're trying to do, and we can help you further. In general though, it's bad form to commit inside a loop, if you're looping over a cursor, so in that case I'd advise committing after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

2000 inserts is close to nothing. Though, it would be far better if you could insert them *at once*, using a single `INSERT` statement, than doing it in a loop.

Generally speaking, commit once you're done with the transaction. It is most probably not ended at every turn of the loop, is it? Besides, committing in a loop (frequently) leads to *ORA-01555 snapshot too old error*.

Saying that "your script sends many queries" - what kind of them? `SELECT`s aren't blocked by anything. `INSERT`s aren't blocked either (I guess you don't lock the whole table, do you)? If you're trying to update rows locked by other user(s), that - obviously - won't work until they are released. The question is: why do those queries wait half a day? Smells like *bad management*.